# UpdateCommand with function

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

I have an UpdateCommand for a grid as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KruSQL %>"  
   UpdateCommand="UPDATE [dbo].[Microbiology] SET RoomNum=@RoomNum, CollDate=@CollDate, WaterFixure=@WaterFixure Where ID=@ID">
<UpdateParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="RoomNum" Type="String" />
   <asp:Parameter Name="WaterFixure" Type="String" />            
   <asp:Parameter Name="CollDate" Type="DateTime" />             
</UpdateParameters>
```

When the user enters a date I need to convert that to UTC. Is there a way to do this from the UpdateCommand - add a function. It didn't work when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

you could write a stored procedure and use that as your UpdateCommand ... inside the stored procedure you could convert the date to utc

Comment: Thanks. Isn't there anyway to do it besides a stored procedure. For example somewhere in the code behind and still make use of the UpdateCommand